# How do I get PyCharm to resolve my SQL references?

Tags: sql-server, pycharm

```
Select * from [Table]
```

The query runs perfectly when I select 'Run query in console'. However, it keeps throwing up an 'Unable to resolve table' warning

I've set my SQL dialect to SQL Server, which is what my workplace uses. I think I've adjusted my scope appropriately as well since my query runs when I use the console

```
Use [Database]; 
Select * from [Table]
```

For some reason that one causes PyCharm to treat the block as a string. Is there a way for me to get the SQL analysis working correctly, or am I just going to have to forego that level of analysis and use  as my dialect?

PyCharm is 2018.1.4. I'm getting SQL query results for the rest of my Python stuff with pyodbc

Answer (score 1):

You need to tell PyCharm what your SQL Dialect is for the project or file.

In Settings, under Languages & Frameworks, select SQL Dialects.

At the top, you can define a global or project dialect (e.g., if you use MySQL for all database connections in your project).

If you have a more complex need, then you can assert the SQL dialect for individual files by adding the file path and choosing the correct dialect for that file.

[image: SQL Dialect for entire project]

Comment: Unfortunately I don't work there anymore, so I can't exactly test it, but this looks like the thing that I would have needed to do. Thanks for responding

Comment: Using MySQL as the dialect was causing the issue for me, even though I'm using MySQL exclusively. Changing the dialect to Generic SQL cleared all of the warnings.

Answer (score 0):

To make resolve work correctly, please add that schema/objects into a database tool window. So, your *database* and *table* inside it should be visible in the database tree.